# Diablo 2 Performing Poorly

Tags: technical-issues, diablo-ii

Diablo 2 is performing very poorly for me.

I tried every display mode (Direct3d, DirectDraw, 3dfx(with glide wrapper)), tried compatibility settings and every solution on the internet but nothing helps. It gets randomly worse in crowded areas.

The interesting thing is that me and my friend are playing Median XL mod. Our computers are pretty much the same except for the GPUs. He has an Nvidia 780 and I have 2x 6970. His game performs fine.

First, I thought the game has problems with multi GPU systems, so I disabled crossfire, but nothing changed.

I think this is about drivers. Should I use an extremely old driver? Which one? Or should I try something else?

Playing with windowed mode doesn't change anything either.

Comment: i mean low framerate. Even playing singleplayer. So its not about a network issue.

Comment: Okay. Let me try and edit this to make it clear then. Lag and slowdown are not the same thing: http://www.howtogeek.com/142193/htg-explains-why-lag-and-low-fps-arent-the-same-thing/

Comment: Windows 10 64 bit with latest updates.

Comment: Does it still perform poorly without the median xl mod?

Comment: Yes, but its perform a bit better without the mod.

Comment: Nothing obvious jumping out at me. You say you've tried "every solution on the internet", which is surely hyperbole and definitely vague. Bunch of suggestions here: http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=888240. Tried switching to 2D?

Comment: Oh, i'm sorry. It looks like i didn't try running at 2D. Now i can run D2 without any performance problems. Thanks!  (& yes i shouldnt have said 'tried every solution on the internet' : ) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your settings to 2D display.

After some research, I found [this thread on Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=888240), which described a problem that sounded similar.

A user said

> Run the video test , and set the graphics to 2d. There is little to no visual diffrence. Solves all your problems.

A few people agree

> I just sucked it up and played in 2d. The difference is minimal, like 5% graphical degredation.. nothing to even notice. The framerate is so much smoother when you do that, it more than makes up for it.
>
> For me, it never dips, automap on and many enemies and multiplayer or not.

In the middle of a complaint about D2's programmers, the thread's OP confirms that this solution improved their frame rate:

> It was said before, going from 3D to 2D in D2, and there's almost no visual quality loss. Then WTF using 3D takes a 70fps and makes it drop to 20 fps when you draw a simple map....